# SafetyKit. A crash simulation

Tags: ios

does anybody know how this [callback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safetykit/sacrashdetectiondelegate/3967489-crashdetectionmanager) could be initiated/simulated on a device/simulator?

> Important
>
> Use the iOS Simulator to test Crash Detection events and the background functionality of your app.
>
> Following a Crash Detection event, the system launches the app in the background. When the app launches, it performs critical tasks related to the Crash Detection event, such as placing a network request or scheduling a local notification. If the system generates multiple Crash Detection events while the app isn’t running, it reports the most recent event on the next app launch. The system may report the same Crash Detection event across different launches of your app, so always check date before processing it.

I've tried to find out any Simulator's menu item. There isn't any.